# Vacations in eXide

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

```
<vacaciones>
    <destino identificador="p023" tipo="unico">
        <titulo>París, la ciudad del amor</titulo>
        <fecha_salida>
              <mes>Marzo</mes>
        </fecha_salida>
        <estancias>
          <hotel estrellas="4">Macuya</hotel>
        </estancias>
    </destino>

    <destino identificador="m036" tipo="unico">
        <titulo>Islas Baleares, ahí mismo</titulo>
        <fecha_salida>
            <mes>Abril</mes>
        </fecha_salida>
        <estancias>
          <hotel estrellas="2">Fuentevino</hotel>
          <hotel estrellas="3">Tresarazos</hotel>
        </estancias>
    </destino>

    <destino identificador="i07" tipo="pack">
        <titulo>Italia, en sí misma</titulo>
        <fecha_salida>
            <mes>Agosto</mes>
        </fecha_salida>
        <estancias>
            <hotel estrellas="3">Mortareilo</hotel>
            <hotel estrellas="2">Sisa da Roca</hotel>
            <hotel estrellas="5">A Gatti</hotel>
            <hotel estrellas="3">La Nostra</hotel>
        </estancias>
    </destino>

    <destino identificador="a456" tipo="unico">
        <titulo>Amsterdam, la Venecia del norte</titulo>
        <fecha_salida>
            <mes>Agosto</mes>
        </fecha_salida>
        <estancias>
            <hotel estrellas="3">The sounders</hotel>
        </estancias>
    </destino>

    <destino identificador="n046" tipo="pack">
        <titulo>Los secretos del Nilo</titulo>
        <fecha_salida>
            <mes>Septiembre</mes>
        </fecha_salida>
        <estancias>
        </estancias>
    </destino>
</vacaciones>
```

I want the nombre of the hotels with more than 2 stars.

I have two different codes:

1.-

```
xquery version "3.1";
for $i in collection("/db/exercise")//destino
where $i//estancias/hotel/@estrellas>"2"
return $i/estancias/hotel/text()
```

Which doesn't give the expected result

2.-

```
xquery version "3.1";
for $i in collection("/db/exercise")//destino
return $i/estancias/hotel[@estrellas>2]/text()
```

Which gives the expected result.

Can anyone explain to me why does the first one not give the result I wanted? Or point out to a web page that explains why?

And why, when I try to get the titulo of every viaje starting in August, it works?

```
for $i in collection("/db/exercise")//destino
where $i/fecha_salida/mes="Agosto"
return ($i/titulo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one

```
hotel/@estrellas>"2"
```

checks for the existence of a `hotel` with an attribute `estrellas`, which attribute has a value greater than "2". Since at least one of these exists, it will return `true`.

The second expression

```
/hotel[@estrellas>2]/text()
```

selects only hotels which have that attribute with that value (i.e, it filters out those hotels which don't have it). The final `/text()` returns their names.

[For one of many examples, see here.](https://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/xpath/xpath-introduction/filtering-node-sets/)

Comment: I think I get it, but I'm not sure

Comment: @BL Believe me when I tell you - it's not simple, nor really intuitive. You just have to stick to it, read (a lot) about it, and do it again and again, until you begin to think "xpathese"...